# How can I use double curly brases in double curly brases in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<p><i class="fas fa-print mr-3"></i>{{ contact.phone2|default_if_none:'{{ contact.phone }}'}}</p>
```

I want a value on double curly braces if_none like above. But it makes an error.
How can I use it, when Django gives [templage tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)?

Comment: You shouldn't use nested braces, does this work? `{{ contact.phone2|default_if_none:contact.phone }}`

Comment: Thanks it work fine. @lain Shelvington